# R Subsetting data frame according to value in a column: only choosing 1

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame that has over 30 columns and 100 rows. Each row is a participant but some participants come from the same school, so some columns are the same for the given participants that share school:

```
part_ID school_ID age   gender sts_school courses_school
1       1         12    F      2967       21  
2       1         11    F      2967       21  
3       1         12    F      2967       21 
4       2         12    F      1450       16  
5       2         11    M      1450       16  
6       3         12    F      2967       21
```

I would like to subset my data so that I only keep one row per school. That is, from the 6 rows above, I'd like to be left with 3 only, one for each different school_ID. The row I keep/discard doesn't matter, since all the info related to school is the same.

Any input?

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$school_ID),]` - this will give you the first row of every school_ID.

Comment: In `dplyr` you can do `df %>% distinct(school_ID, .keep_all = TRUE)`.